# error al validar en angular 12 sólo con Password y ConfirmPassword, lo demás valida bien, estoy trabajando con API Rest net core

Tags: angular12

este es  mi servicio.

user.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
  import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


  @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class UserService {

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private http:HttpClient) { }
 readonly BaseURI = 'http://localhost:4324/api';


   formModel = this.fb.group({
   UserName: ['', Validators.required],
   Email: ['', Validators.email],
   FullName: [''],
   Passwords: this.fb.group({
   Password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
  ConfirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
   })
  });

     register() {
     var body = {
     UserName: this.formModel.value.UserName,
     Email: this.formModel.value.Email,
     FullName: this.formModel.value.FullName,
     Password: this.formModel.value.Passwords.Password
     };
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI + '/ApplicationUser/Register', body);
    }
   }
```

Este es mi ts.

**registration.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { UserService } from 'src/app/share/user.service';
  import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
 import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


  @Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
   templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
   styleUrls: []
  })
  export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(public service:UserService,private toastr: ToastrService,fb:FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
   this.service.formModel.reset();
  }

     onSubmit() {
     this.service.register().subscribe(
   (res: any) => {
    if (res.succeeded) {
      this.service.formModel.reset();
      this.toastr.success('New user created!', 'Registration successful.');
    } else {
      res.errors.forEach((element: { code: any; description: string | undefined; }) => {
        switch (element.code) {
          case 'DuplicateUserName':
            this.toastr.error('Username is already taken','Registration failed.');
            break;

          default:
          this.toastr.error(element.description,'Registration failed.');
            break;
        }
      });
    }
     },
     err => {
      console.log(err);
      }
       );
      }
     }
```

Este es mi HTML donde  tengo el error, no valida el Password  y ConfirmPassword.

```
 <form [formGroup]="service.formModel" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="form-group required">
<label>Username</label>
<input class="form-control" formControlName="UserName">
<label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['UserName'].touched && 
 service.formModel.controls['UserName'].errors?.required">This
  field is mandatory.</label>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Email</label>
<input class="form-control" formControlName="Email">
<label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['Email'].touched && 
  service.formModel.controls['Email'].errors?.email">Invalid
  email address.</label>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Full Name</label>
<input class="form-control" formControlName="FullName">
 </div>
 <div formGroupName="Passwords">
<div class="form-group required">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="Password">
  <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['Passwords.Password'].touched 
  && service.formModel.controls['Passwords.Password'].errors?.required">This
    field is mandatory.</label>
  <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['Passwords.Password'].touched 
 && service.formModel.controls['Passwords.Password'].errors?.passwordMismatch">Confirm
    Password does not match.</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group required">
  <label>Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="ConfirmPassword">
  <label class="text-danger" 
  *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['Passwords.ConfirmPassword'].touched && 
  service.formModel.controls['Passwords.ConfirmPassword'].errors?.required">This
   field is mandatory.</label>
  <label class="text-danger" 
  *ngIf="service.formModel.controls['Passwords.ConfirmPassword'].touched && 
   service.formModel.controls['Passwords.ConfirmPassword'].errors?.passwordMismatch">Confirm
    Password does not match.</label>
     </div>
     </div>
    <br>
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 offset-md-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" 
      [disabled]="!service.formModel.valid">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
     </div>
   <br>
 </form>
```